# How to deal with a $0\Omega$ resistor connected in parallel?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

There is a side without resistance, what is the equivalent resistance?

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Edited your question somewhat heavily - please check that it's still asking what you want to ask. If not, you can rollback the edit here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/135679/revisions.

Comment: How to deal with a 0Ω resistor connected in parallel? Ans: With wire cutters. It's called a short, and you need to snip it off before anything bracketted inside it can work :) Otherwise, from a circuit description, the whole link, and anything in parallel, is replaced by a single, equipotential point in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Well I imagine you know how to add resistors in parallel:

$$R = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}+...+\frac{1}{R_n}}$$

Of course if you try to put a resistor with $R=0$ in there you run into $\frac{1}{0}$. You can probably take a limit and show that the equivalent resistance is $0$ if there's a zero resistor in parallel. This makes sense. If current is offered two paths, one with $0$ resistance and another with finite resistance, then all the current will flow through the zero resistance path and the other resistors in parallel carry no current and can be ignored.

After that you just need to deal with the other resistors connected in series, should be easy.

In practice of course you'd never have exactly zero resistance along a circuit, except perhaps using superconductors.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to gaining insight to the answer is to note that, for two parallel resistors, the equivalent resistance is

$$R_{EQ} = \frac{R_1R_2}{R_1 + R_2} = \frac{R_2}{1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1}}$$

as long as either resistance is not equal to zero.

Now, let $R_2$ go to almost zero while holding $R_1$ constant.  When $R_2 \ll R_1$, the equivalent resistance is approximately

$$R_{EQ} \approx R_2$$

So, it is clear that, as $R_2$ approaches zero, the equivalent resistance approaches zero.

---

Another approach is to recall two important results:

- Parallel connected resistors have the same voltage across
- An ideal wire has zero volts across for any current through

Thus, if a resistor is in parallel with a wire, there is zero volts across the resistor.

If there is zero volts across the resistor, there is zero current through the resistor.

If there is zero current through the resistor, the resistor can be removed without affecting the circuit.

Thus, a resistor in parallel with a wire is equivalent to a wire by itself.

Comment: Fine, But why there is Zero Volts in the other Parallel resistors?

Comment: @Koojo, if you redraw the circuit, you'll see that the three 12 ohm resistors and a wire are in parallel.  Parallel circuit elements have identical voltage across, thus, there is 0V across the three 12 ohm resistors and they can all be removed without affecting the circuit.